# Maven build profile execute when a child module pom defines a property

Tags: java, maven

I would like to have a common build profile for modules which define a specific property. In my case I'm running the `jar-with-dependencies` plugin and wish for it to only run when a module defines the `main.class` property.

I have the following in my parent POM:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>executable-jar</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>main.class</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                            <phase>package</phase> <!--  bind to the packaging phase -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

It will not be built unless I define `-Dmain.class` when running the Maven command so it looks like it's not detecting the property in the modules where it counts. Can this be triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going at it the wrong way. [Profiles are not intended to be used this way](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Your configuration does not work because a profile activated with a `<property>` only targets the presence (or absence) of a *system* property, not just any Maven property. This is because the active profiles needs to be calculated right from the start of the build, while Maven properties are set after that (you can even set properties during the build)

What you really want to do here is to factor out the configuration of the `maven-assembly-plugin` in a parent POM. The Maven way for that is to go through the declaration of a [`<pluginManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management):

> Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way, except that rather than configuring plugin information for this particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children.

This means that you can configure a plugin management for the `maven-assembly-plugin` and let the project for which you want that plugin to be invoked reference it.

As such, in your parent POM, you'll have the following:

```xml
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This declares a management section for the `maven-assembly-plugin`. For this to be used by your modules, you then need the following in your child POM:

```xml
<properties>
  <main.class>MyMainClass</main.class>
</properties>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This declares that the module will reference the management section in the parent POM. And Maven will correctly use the build property `main.class` in this case.

For the modules where this plugin is not to be invoked, you just need to omit the plugin declaration of the `maven-assembly-plugin` and nothing will happen.